# Copy a top level element into each element of an array using Jolt

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I am working on to push down the top level field into each element of the array inside it.

***I want to push 'sourceEntity' into the each element of 'supportedCountries' array and 'supportedCurrencies' Array***

input JSON:

```
{
  "description": "SUPPORTED_COUNTRY_CURRENCY",
  "id": "20190902025202944",
  "type": "devuae-SUPPORTED_COUNTRY_CURRENCY",
  "sourceEntity": "EBI",
  "sourceChannel": "COR",
  "timestamp": "1567421549887",
  "supportedCountries": [
    {
      "code": "IN",
      "name": "India",
      "supportedCurrencies": [
        {
          "code": "JOD",
          "name": "JORDANIAN DINAR",
          "isLocal": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected OUTPUT:

```
{
  "description": "SUPPORTED_COUNTRY_CURRENCY",
  "id": "20190902025202944",
  "type": "devuae-SUPPORTED_COUNTRY_CURRENCY",
  "sourceEntity": "EBI",
  "sourceChannel": "COR",
  "timestamp": "1567421549887",
  "supportedCountries": [
    {
      "EntityID": "EBI",
      "code": "IN",
      "name": "India",
      "supportedCurrencies": [
        {
          "UnitID": "EBI",
          "code": "JOD",
          "name": "JORDANIAN DINAR",
          "isLocal": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this might help,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "description": "description",
      "id": "id",
      "type": "type",
      "sourceEntity": "sourceEntity",
      "sourceChannel": "sourceChannel",
      "timestamp": "timestamp",
      "supportedCountries": {
        "*": {
          //Shifting sourceEntity from the level 1
          "@(2,sourceEntity)": "supportedCountries[&1].EntityID",
          "code": "supportedCountries[&1].code",
          "name": "supportedCountries[&1].name",
          "supportedCurrencies": {
            "*": {
              //Shifting sourceEntity from the level 1
              "@(4,sourceEntity)": "supportedCountries[&1].supportedCurrencies[&1].UnitID",
              "code": "supportedCountries[&1].supportedCurrencies[&1].code",
              "name": "supportedCountries[&1].supportedCurrencies[&1].name",
              "isLocal": "supportedCountries[&1].supportedCurrencies[&1].isLocal"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```